# Does a nilpotent operator always have a Jordan representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

(Supposing the Jordan representation exists) Since a Jordan block associated to $\lambda$ has the form $J= \lambda I + N$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $N$ a nilpotent matrix. One could find a base where the nilpotent operator $f$ of order $r$ has the matrix representation of $N$, which in turn would be a block diagonal matrix with some Jordan blocks of dimension at most $r$ (with at least one block of dimension equal $r$), all associated to $\lambda=0$.

However, this form always exist if we are working on a algebraically closed field. What happens if the vector field $V$ is not algebraically closed? Can I still say that there is a Jordan representation of $f$? I was thinking maybe there is a way of showing that $\det(f)=\lambda^{\dim(V)}$.

Comment: What does it mean for a vector field to be algebraically closed?

Comment: It is enough that the eigenvalues are in the field. The basis in which the matrix is the Jordan normal form is computed solving linear systems where the coefficients belong to the extension of the field of coefficients by the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the vector space is final dimensional.

A linear operator $T$ has a Jordan canonical form (there is a Jordan canonical basis for $V$ relative to $T$) if and only the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits into linear factors; when the ground field is algebraically closed you get that "for free", but even over non-algebraically closed fields some operators will have Jordan canonical forms (even if they are not diagonalizable).

A nilpotent operator $N$ always satisfies the polynomial $x^k$ for some $k\gt 0$. That means the minimal polynomial is a power of $x$. Since every irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial must divide the minimal polynomial, that means the characteristic polynomial of $N$ must be $(-1)^nx^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$. Thus, the characteristic polynomial of $N$ splits into linear factors, so $N$ will necessarily have a Jordan canonical basis. This holds over any ground field, algebraically closed or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the operator $N$ satisfies the polinomial $x^k$, please.

Comment: @leplata: That's the definition of nilpotent: that some power of $N$ is the zero transformation.